# How do I get an Ionic image URL from an image uploaded to Firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am uploading an image from the phone in Ionic using Cordova:

```
async takePhoto(sourceType: number) {
    try {

        const options: CameraOptions = {
            quality: 50,
            targetHeight: 100,
            targetWidth: 100,
            destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
            correctOrientation: true,
            sourceType: sourceType
        }
        const result = await this.camera.getPicture(options);
        const image = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${result}`;
        this.pictures = storage().ref('pictures/myphotos');
        this.pictures.putString(image, 'data_url');
        this.Url = this.pictures.getDownloadURL();
              }

catch(e){
  console.error(e);
}}
```

I am trying to get items from:

```
<ion-label>Item Name</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="shoppingItem.itemName"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Amount / Day</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="shoppingItem.itemFee"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Description</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="shoppingItem.itemDescription">
</ion-input>
</ion-item>

<form-upload></form-upload>
  <button ion-button (click)="takePhoto(0)"> Upload Photo</button>
  <button ion-button (click)="addShopppingItem(shoppingItem)"> Submit </button>

addShopppingItem(shoppingItem: ShoppingItem){
this.shoppingItemRef$.push({itemName:this.shoppingItem.itemName,
  itemFee:this.shoppingItem.itemFee,
  temDescription:this.shoppingItem.itemDescription,
  itemInstructions:this.shoppingItem.itemInstructions,
  itemCategory: this.shoppingItem.itemCategory,
  itemDelivery: this.shoppingItem.itemDelivery,
  url:this.Url
})
```

I am getting these items but I am unable to get the URL of the image into the correct node.

[image]

I need the node to be like this in order to display the images using a query later:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question...you retrieved correctly from the database the downloadUrl or not?

Comment: I do receive the Url but in the format of the first picture , i want to get it in the format of the second picture of which i am able only when using snapshot, but i cannot get the snapshot instance from uploading using camera options as in the code above. From the node in the first picture i want to be able to display the picture in a ionic list using <img>